# TinyMCE search and replace plugin not working on Firefox 47.0.2

Tags: tinymce

I am facing the issue with search and replace plugin. it is not working on firefox browser v 47.0.2.

I am using Version: 5.0.5 (2019-05-09)

Please do the needfull.

Answer (score 0):

That is a rather old browser and is not officially supported by TinyMCE at this time.  I have tested TinyMCE 5.0.x in the current / supported Firefox releases (60ESR and 67) and it works correctly in these browsers.

We have this page that provides a list of supported browsers:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/general-configuration-guide/system-requirements/#browsercompatibility

> TinyMCE fully supports the most recent version of all browsers listed above. TinyMCE also supports the latest Extended Support Release (ESR) from each vendor (e.g. Firefox).